# Is there an adjective describing some person or group of people who blindly follow a leader figure, especially with negative connotations?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a word describing those who act like sheep to the shepherd, blindly following the leader figure, without considering their own actions. If I could conceive of such a word, I might make it something like "igorical" (reminiscent of Igor, who blindly follows his mad scientist leader).

Example of use (applying to behavior):

It is in such *igorical* behavior that such an election can arise.

Example of use (applying to people):

It is in the existence of such *igorical* people that such an election can arise.

Comment: Search for similar questions. I believe this is a duplicate of a question asked within the last month or two.

Answer (score 2):

A relatively recent coinage is [sheeple](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheeple). It means exactly what you want, albeit a noun rather than an adjective.

The word appears to date back to the 1940s, but I've come across it several times in social media lately, usually in the formulation ["Wake up, sheeple!"](http://xkcd.com/1013/)

It hasn't made it to spellcheck yet, though.

Comment: Haha, I love it

Comment: It's a noun, though, not an adjective.

Comment: That just means it's a bit more limited in how colorfully it can be used

Answer (score 1):

The obvious, off-the-cuff answer is "**lemming**" or "**lemming mentality**," but I suspect that's a little cliché and/or informal for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**sheeple** or **sheople** People who are meekly submissive or easily swayed (Sheep + people)

> Sheeple (a portmanteau of "sheep" and "people") is a derogatory term that highlights the passive herd behavior of people easily controlled by a governing power which likens them to sheep, a herd animal that is easily led about. The term is used to describe those who voluntarily acquiesce to a suggestion without critical analysis or research in large part because the majority of others possess a similar mindset.
>
> <sub>-- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheeple)</sub>

Comment: Verbose just beat you to it

Comment: Welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. This would be a better answer with some cited definitions from authoritative sources.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

“acolyte” in the sense of follower, has been used for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

The word "**ovine**" is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ovine) as

> Relating to or resembling sheep

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a word ***sheeplike*** which has a definition to mean exactly that.

> It is in such ***sheeplike*** behavior that such an election can arise.
>
> It is in the existence of such ***sheeplike*** people that such an election
>   can arise.

Macmillan:

> **[sheeplike](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sheeplike)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE* SHOWING DISAPPROVAL
>
> behaving like sheep, especially in a way that
>   shows an inability to think for yourself
>
> They demand sheeplike obedience.